# Can I force generation of a JVM crash log file?

Tags: java, jvm, crash

The log file from a JVM crash contains all sorts of useful information for debugging, such as shared libraries loaded and the complete environment. Can I force the JVM to generate one of these programmatically; either by executing code that crashes it or some other way? Or alternatively access the same information another way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try throwing an OutOfMemoryError and adding the -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError jvm argument.  This is new as of 1.6 as are the other tools suggested by McDowell.
http://blogs.oracle.com/watt/resource/jvm-options-list.html

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576672/force-or-generate-jvm-core-dump

Comment: That other question seems to be for a core dump that one could send to the JVM implementer, e.g. IBM, rather than an `hs_err_pid*.log`.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [JDK Development Tools](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/), in particular the [Troubleshooting Tools](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/#troubleshoot) for dumping the heap, printing config info, etcetera.

Comment: Of the tools, [`jstack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) seems the most promising, in the form `jstack -l -F -m <pid>` (`-F` not needed if process is not hung). This gets you stacks of all threads, in mixed mode (Java and native) and locked synchronisers, even if the process is hung.

Comment: Or see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/toc.html for Oracle Java 8 (previous links are 6, but probably not very different content).

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS I force core dump on jdk 11 process via

```
kill -4 <PID>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this can be done with the IBM JDK as I was playing around with their stack analyzer some time ago. One option to force the dump would just to cause an outOfMemoryException.

These tools may provide some clues http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ibmtools1/

Comment: The link seems to be about a tool available only to IBM customers, of which I am not one.