# Is the -Xdebug option supported in JDK 1.5?

Tags: java, trace, xdebug

I couldn't find any suitable documentation for the same. In any case, which is the best way to generate trace reports while running a JVM process (a tool provided by SUN in its JDK bundle preferably) so that any JVM crashes can be logged?

Thanks in advance,

z0ltan

Answer (score 1):

According to ["java - the Java application launcher"](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html), in the JDK1.5 documentation, XDebug is a non-standard option:

> Start with support for [JVMDI](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jvmdi-spec.html) enabled. JVMDI has been deprecated and is not used for debugging in J2SE 5.0, so this option isn't needed for debugging in J2SE 5.0.

JVMDI is deprecated as of J2SE 5.0. [JVMTI](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html/) should be used instead.

For traces during the execution, some clues are in the question ["Can I force generation of a JVM crash log file?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337793/can-i-force-generation-of-a-jvm-crash-log-file), but mostly for JDK1.6.
For 1.5, those [troubleshooting tools](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/index.html#debug) might be useful.